# How to make listview begin with certain word in all raws?

Tags: c#, listview

I'm a beginner with c#, so if anyone can please help.

I download things like this all the time 
"http://ourquraan.com/quran/3bdalrahman_al3osy/001.mp3",
so I thought why not make an app to make it easy for me.

The idea is I want to make an editor program to give the program the first part of the link, then I insert the range of numbers from 1 to 114 to be put after it.

Now I managed to get the ranges correct but what I can't do is to make the first part of the link a constant in every raw of the listview.

In a brief way I want the result to be:

```
"link/ " + "1" + ".mp3"
"link/" + "2" + ".mp3"
.
.
.
.
"link/ " + "114" + ".mp3"

what i get is 
"link/" + "1" + ".mp3"
2
3
4
.
.
.
.
114
```

The current code is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     

    if (textBox1.Text=="" |textBox2.Text=="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please specifi a multiple and upper limtit.", "Error");  
    }
    else
    {
        int number = 0 , limit = 0 ;
        string currentnumber = "";
        number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        limit = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        do
        {
            number++;
            if (number == limit)
            { 
            }
            else
            {
                currentnumber += number + "\n";
            }
        } while (number < limit);

        foreach (int item in currentnumber)

            richTextBox1.Text = textBox3.Text + textBox2.Text + "\n"  + currentnumber + textBox1.Text + "\n";

    }

}
```

`textBox1` has the first range

`textBox2` has the second range

`textBox3` has the link

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: please include the current code

Comment: And Where is the ListView in the updated code?

Comment: @un-lucky i replaced it with richTextBox1 but still the same idea

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to generate the required list as List you can bind the ListView with this List:

```
 string linkFormat=@"\Link\{0:000}.mp3";
 List<string> LinkList = Enumerable.Range(1, 114)
                                   .Select(x => String.Format(linkFormat, x))
                                   .ToList();
```

To get the List Displayed in the `richTextBox1` as its Text you can use the Following code:

```
richTextBox1.Text = String.Join("\n", LinkList);
```

Comment: it's working bro just i need the range to be in this form 001 ,002 ....114
because if it's 1.mp3 the link won't work

Comment: @ahmed.soli then change the `linkFormat` to `@"\Link\{0:000}.mp3";`
more information on formatting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) .

Comment: @MongZhu : It is an open site, you can update the answer; anyway thanks for the comment i have updated that

Comment: @un-lucky it is your answer why should I fiddle around in that. :)

Comment: @MongZhu thanks for your help it's working perfectly now

Comment: @ahmed.soli , thats nice